# Snowflake database: Question on table performance which is stored in snowflake

Tags: sql, performance, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, etl

We have a continuous insert, update, and delete in a table that is in snowflake DB,  can this slow down the performance of a table in snowflake over the period of time?

Comment: How many rows are being updated/inserted in the table ? Your Select from the table should not be slowed as you know Snowflake  stores the data in immutable micros partitions, if you update or delete then a new micro partition is created, but it depends upon the Table size / number of rows in the table and the SELECT statement that you are doing on the table.

Comment: We pull the data from Oracle and use the MERGE statement to insert, update and delete the data. So technically whole table is used in merge operations and there are millions of rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. For two reasons.

because the changes of the INSERT, UPDATE, & DELETE alter the fragment the partition data, thus even if the same number of ROW are present after N hours/days, the layout of the rows can become unaligned to the affinity of queries you run, thus your performance profile can go from highly prunes partition reads, to full table reads.

Also with large number of changes, even if the data is all perfectly ordered after then, the share fact many changes are being made with mean you end up with way too many partitions, which slows down you SQL compilations.

You also can have bad performance if you are INSERT, UPDATE, & DELETE to the same table at the same time, as the second operation will be blocked by the former. This can waste wall clock, and credit allocation (if they are different warehouses)

Some things you can do to avoid this, is run clustering, rebuild the tables in "down time". Not delete the data, but insert into "delete tables" and then left join and exclude matches. We have done all the above.

Comment: I like the "delete tables" hack. I would fill them during the day, then use to actually delete data just before the rebuild, and this way keep them tiny.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. :) One question: rebuild the tables in "downtime"; can I use CREATE OR REPLACE TRANSIENT TABLE <NEW _TABLE> AS SELECT * FROM <OLD_TABLE>?

Comment: @swanandkulkarni yes that is one method, you would most likely want COPY GRANTS also. https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-table.html#variant-syntax There is also methods where you make a new table and SWAP them. depends on your control of writing processes. Also if the table is not currently TRANSIENT you don't want to make the replacement TRANSIENT. you want them to be same.

Comment: @Simeon Piglgrim thanks for the reply.